# Web Service retornando valor inválido

Tags: android, mysql, json, web-service

Bom pessoal, recentemnte fiz um pergunta com o titulo:

> Aplicação apresentando este erro: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException

Mas pesquisando cheguei a uma conclusao diferente na qual eu tinha criado a pergunta, por isso estou criando uma nova...

O Erro é o seguinte, montei um Web Service para minha aplicação consumir e sempre que minha aplicação acessa ele ele retorna com um valor nulo, buscando no localhost eu obtenho isso:

```
{"products":[{"pid":"1","name":"iPhone","price":"4500.00","created_at":"2015-02-18 20:02:20","updated_at":null},
             {"pid":"2","name":"Motorola Moto G 2014","price":"800.00","created_at":"2015-02-19 18:56:46","updated_at":null},
             {"pid":"4","name":"LG G3","price":"1200.00","created_at":"2015-02-19 21:49:25","updated_at":null}],"success":1}
```

Mas eu desconfio que os "[]" estao implicando, nao sei direito, nunca mechi com JSON e nao sei se o problema esta em minha classe Java ou se esta no meu Web Service...

Meu get_all_products.php:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["price"] = $row["price"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Produto nao Encotrado";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Minha AllProductsActivity.java

```
package br.com.products;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://XXX.XXX.X.X/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Minha JSONParser.java

```
package br.com.products;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Minha LogCat:

```
02-20 21:41:27.123: I/Choreographer(1950): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 21:41:29.021: I/Choreographer(1950): Skipped 183 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 21:41:29.744: I/Choreographer(1950): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 21:41:30.742: E/JSON Parser(1950): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ï»¿ï»¿<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950): Process: br.com.products, PID: 1950
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at br.com.products.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:130)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at br.com.products.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     ... 4 more
02-20 21:41:32.516: I/Choreographer(1950): Skipped 299 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 21:41:33.491: I/Choreographer(1950): Skipped 101 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 21:41:33.835: I/Choreographer(1950): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 21:41:39.694: I/Choreographer(1950): Skipped 158 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity br.com.products.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{22c7d125 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,232} that was originally added here
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at br.com.products.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:117)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at br.com.products.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:57)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-20 21:41:41.280: E/WindowManager(1950):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-20 21:41:41.289: I/Choreographer(1950): Skipped 170 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 21:41:41.618: I/Choreographer(1950): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.


Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ï»¿ï»¿<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

E aconteçe quando tento executar uma busca de todos os produtos cadastrados no meu banco de dados...

Alguem poderia me ajudar? Ja pesquisei bastante e nenhum resolveu meu erro...

Comment: Sabe dizer em qual linha ocorre o erro?

Comment: Os colchetes fazem parte do Json.
de uma lida aqui vai te ajudar muito http://www.json.org/

Comment: @AndréRibeiro acicionei minha LogCat completa, da uma olhada nela e voce vai ver os erros, e também adicionei minha classe JSONParser se ajudar... sabe o que pode ser? preciso muito fazer essa conexao...

Comment: Ninguem sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente não sei se está utilizando, mas recomendo utilizar essas duas ferramentas para trabalhar e validar seu Json, antes de consumir na App.

1- http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
Valida o formato do seu JSON,

2 - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
Você consegue testar o consumo do seu webservice,

O problema parece que realmente é o valor null, você vai ter que deixar o "updated_at":"" ou assim "updated_at":"null"

Oque pode fazer pra ver se resolve é fazer esse ternário:

```
$product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"] == null ? "" : $row["updated_at"];
```

Olhando no seu LogCat, deu pra ver o erro no momento da tentativa de conversão do null.

02-20 21:41:30.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1950): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference